# how i can get the string after specific character in my case :?

Tags: c#

```
str="Brand : TROLLBEADS";

int length = str.Length;

length = length - 6;

str = str.Substring(6, length);
```

i want to display "TROLLBEADS" 
and want to discard other remaining string

Comment: What is the character after which you want to get the string? The last whitespace? The colon? Everything after and including T?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using `:` delimiter if it is fixed

```
var result = str.Split(':')[1].Trim();
```

or if your string can have multiple `:` in that case

```
var result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Split is nice, but a bit too much. You can just specify the start position for substring.

```
string str="Brand : TROLLBEADS";
string val = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(":") + 1);
Console.WriteLine(val);
```